# Concatenate list from JSON array

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

Let's say I have json in the database of items:

Row1:

```
{"Id": "1", "Items": [{"Item": "Test Item", "Price": "$5.00"}, {"Item": "Test Item #2", "Price": "$15.00"}]}
```

Row2:

```
{"Id": "2", "Items": [{"Item": "Test Item #3", "Price": "$1.00"}, {"Item": "Test Item #1", "Price": "$4.00"}]}
```

How do I get rows formatted like this (`|` is column seperator):

```
1 | Test Item, Test Item #2
2 | Test Item #3, Test Item #1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  ID || '|' || ARRAY_TO_STRING( ARRAY_AGG( ITEMS ), ', ')
FROM
    (
        SELECT T.J->>'Id' AS ID, json_array_elements((T.J->'Items')::json)->>'Item' AS ITEMS
        FROM
        (
            SELECT ('{"Id": "1", "Items": [{"Item": "Test Item", "Price": "$5.00"}, {"Item": "Test Item #2", "Price": "$15.00"}]}')::json AS J
            UNION all
            SELECT ('{"Id": "2", "Items": [{"Item": "Test Item #3", "Price": "$1.00"}, {"Item": "Test Item #1", "Price": "$4.00"}]}')::json AS J
        ) T
    ) T
GROUP   BY ID
```

Comment: Wasn't looking for a literal `|` but this leads me to what I need.